# Azure OpenID profile scope - picture not included?

Tags: azure, azure-active-directory, microsoft-graph-api

[In this documentation link](https://developer.microsoft.com/en-us/graph/docs/concepts/permissions_reference#openid-permissions) the OpenID scope `profile` states access to a user's profile photo. When consenting users (tested in both personal and organization accounts), the consent does include the word profile photo.

However, when I decode my JWT id_token I receive from openid, I get no such claim. What am I missing?

My request is

```
https://login.microsoftonline.com/common/oauth2/v2.0/authorize?
&client_id=myclientid
&response_type=id_token
&redirect_uri=myredirecturi
&response_mode=form_post
&scope=openid%20email%20profile
&nonce=mynonce
```

Comment: Have you add `profile` permission in your v2 endpoint App?

Comment: Also, if you added the permission and when you do consent, it will shows this massage:`The App will be able to see your basic profile (name, picture, user name).`

Comment: Yes, I have added the permissions in the endpoint.
I'm also not able to get the email claim from some organizations - are there possibly restrictions on these claims? I would have thought openID claims can't be restricted

Comment: I don't believe the v2 Endpoint returns the `picture` claim. My guess is this is because AAD doesn't provide a publicly accessible URL to a user's profile photo (the spec defines `picture` as a direct URL for an image). The docs for the Id Token don't mention this claim either: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/active-directory/develop/active-directory-v2-tokens#id-tokens

Comment: thanks Mark. that's certainly a possible explanation for the picture claim. Would you have any ideas on the email claim in the comment above?